# Custom blade directive not working since upgrade from Laravel 5.7 to Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-5.7, laravel-5.8

I have some custom directives for Ziggyroutes in Laravel. In Laravel 5.7 they work perfectly fine, now i have upgraded to Laravel 5.8 and they stopped working. If I call a custom directive they just print out plain text.

I have tried it in a clean project and it works in there. And I have cleared my cache with view:clear, cache:clear and config:clear

For example I have:

```php
 \Blade::directive('routes', function($group = null){
            return "<?php echo app('" . BladeRouteGenerator::class . "')->generate({$group}); ?>";
        });
```

And in the Blade I call it like this:

```php
 @routes()
```

with give a result of just plain text stating `@routes()`.

So what I would expect and what should happen is that a list with all routes will be pasted to the blade. 
 And what is happening now at this time is that it just print it in plain text `@routes()`.

So what can be the problem to this behavior. Did I miss something with the upgrade from Laravel 5.7 to 5.8?

update: Apparently the package `htmlmin` was breaking the whole thing [link to issue](https://github.com/HTMLMin/Laravel-HTMLMin/issues/127) so after removing the package it worked again.

Comment: This is working for me. Did you add the directive code to your `AppServiceProvider` as shown in https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#extending-blade ?

Comment: @BramVerstraten Well it is in a separate ServiceProvider that is extending the ServiceProvider and then is loaded in the app.php. I have tried to put it directly in the AppServiceProvider because the documentation said so. But it still wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

problem is here vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Blade.php:34

if u change this return from previous version

```
return static::$app['view']->getEngineResolver()->resolve('blade')->getCompiler();
```

then u must view:clear

custom directive is working.. but this is not good... I think problem is with alias blade.compiler but I don't know where.

Any help?

**Update:**

u have 2 options.

First option is `composer remove htmlmin/htmlmin`

or

second options is:

publish all vendor assets

```
$ php artisan vendor:publish
```

This will create a `config/htmlmin.php`

edit this config and set `'blade' => false,`

Comment: Hi Erik Selecky, thanks for the anwser. For my problem it was the package `htmlmin` that ruined it all. After deleting it every thing works again.